# Double free or corruption in OpenMP

Tags: openmp

I'm trying to implement a parallel brute force substring searching algorithm. Each thread gets a starting and ending index, and since I'm running it with 4 threads, each thread will do a quarter of the work.

Now, when I run the function once, everything is perfectly fine (works with 4 threads), however since the function is of void type, I store my result (index where the substring was located within the larger string) in a global variable 'ans'.

```
int ans = -1;

void bruteForce(string mainString, string subString)
{
    int tid, nthreads;
    #pragma omp parallel private (tid) shared (nthreads, ans)
    {
        tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        int j = 0;
        int start = tid * (mainString.size() / nthreads);
        int end = start + mainString.size() / nthreads;

        for(int i = start; i < end; i++)
        {
            if(ans == -1)
            {
                while(j < subString.size())
                {
                    if(mainString[i + j] != subString[j]) break;
                    if(j == subString.size() - 1)
                    {
                        #pragma omp critical
                        {
                            #pragma omp flush
                            ans = i;
                        }
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                j = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do, is reset the 'ans' to -1 either after the function is completed or before it starts, however when I try to do that, i get this error, along with memory map and backtrace.

```
double free or corruption (out): 0xb5b00468 ***
```

Is there are a reason why I can't change 'ans' to -1 within the for loop show bellow?

```
    start = get_timestamp();
    for(int x = 0; x < N; x++)
    {
        show_percent(x, N);
        bruteForce(STRING, WORD);
    }
    end = get_timestamp();
```

Comment: You should post the solution in a separed post, not in the question. Also, please do not put [solved] in your title. For more information see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172501/community-edit-request-solved-fixed-answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with changing ans. You need to put a limit on **(i+j)** in the while loop of **brutForce()**.

Say mainString = "THIS" and subString="XXX".
So each thread gets

> T | H | I | S

For the last thread your start=3, and end=4. Also subString.size() = 3;

so In the while loop you are accessing mainString[i+j] where j = 0->2 ==> (i+j) = 3->5.

Comment: I actually solved the problem a few hours after posting this, however it had nothing to do with what you just said. On the other hand, you did find another error in my code which I stupidly overlooked, so thank you for that. I'll post the fixed code in a minute. Cheers!

Comment: Also, this wouldn't give a Double free or corruption error, but a Segmentation fault, since it's accessing an array out of its bounds, rather than trying to delete something twice.

Comment: I just saw your solution. I think you did the same mistake again. For the last thread using above example ("THIS" | "XXX") your new end:
end = 4-3 = 1. And the start = 3. **i Loop** will not even start. You are trying to limit j by changing "end" which is a limit for "i". Also you have to consider the situation when mainString%nthreads !=0.

Comment: yeah i know, i'll add those later. currently i'm working with a 100k sized string so it doesn't cause any problems. again, the bug you've noticed has nothing to do with double free or corruption, at most it could cause a seg fault.

Answer (score 0):

*As stated by the original poster of the question:*

---

**SOLUTION**

Here's a fixed and working version of the code. I've only just started messing about with OpenMP, and it seems really picky with how and where you declare your variables, and how you pass them on to individual threads, so if someone could enlighten me as to why these changes fixed the code, that would be great. Also, the `#pragma omp parallel for` i added substantially improved performance of the program.

```
int ans = -1;

void bruteForce(const string mainString, const string subString)
{
    ans = -1;
    int tid, nthreads, start, end, j, i;
    #pragma omp parallel private (tid, start, end, j) shared (nthreads, ans)
    {
        tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        start = tid * (mainString.size() / nthreads);
        end = start + mainString.size() / nthreads;
        if(tid == (nthreads - 1)) 
            end = end - subString.size();
        j = 0;

        #pragma omp parallel for
        for(i = start; i < end; i++)
        {
            if(ans == -1)
            {
                while(j < subString.size())
                {
                    if(mainString[i + j] != subString[j]) break;
                    if(j == subString.size() - 1)
                    {
                        #pragma omp critical
                        {
                            ans = i;
                        }
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                j = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```